# Is it possible to call a UDF from a trigger in other database table?

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-functions, database-trigger

I have 2 databases, say DB1 and DB2. DB1 contains a table, say MyTable, and DB2 contains a UDF, say MyFunction.

I need to create a trigger for insert in the MyTable table in DB1. That trigger should call the UDF in DB2.

I tried this in the trigger:

```
    DECLARE @result INT
    SELECT @result = DB2.[dbo].[MyFunction]
```

But that does not work.

Is there a way to do that?

Regards
Jaime

Comment: In what way does it "not work"? What you have posted is not a trigger. Please post the full trigger definition and describe your issue.

Comment: Does not work means function is not found. To post the full trigger is useless..  think a normal trigger and inside it, the code I posted.

Comment: Please at least post the actual error message.

Comment: I just tried a simple example and successfully called a scalar function in a different database. I'm guessing there is a syntax issue. What _type_ of function are you calling? Try adding `()` to the end of your function call

Comment: The error is function not found. I have tried to call a SP first, but intellisense does not even shows the other database name. When I use a function, intellisense shows the other database but it only shows the tables, nothing else. I forced the name of the function and a not found error is shown. Intellisense gives the clue . If it does  not show the function, it might mean trigger does not allow that. I don't think it is a syntax error.

Comment: "function not found" is not a T-SQL error message. I'm not sure why you are unable to post it. Please see my answer below for an example of what I mean. When I get an error that I'm not sure about the first thing I do is google it, so that's why it's important to post an error message verbatim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I create a trigger and reference a scalar function in a different DB without the required trailing `()` (as per the original post)

```
CREATE TRIGGER tTEST on MD.Table
FOR INSERT
AS
SELECT DB2.dbo.LocalDateTime
```

I get

> > Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure tTEST, Line 4 [Batch Start Line 185]
> >     The multi-part identifier "DB2.dbo.LocalDateTime" could not be bound.

I guess this is the error you're getting?

So add the required brackets to it:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tTEST on MD.Table
FOR INSERT
AS
SELECT DB2.dbo.LocalDateTime()
```

Comment: Thanks. In fact, that was the error. By using parenthesis, problem was solved.